# Rails - Renaming model ID in URL with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested route and I have redefined the ID part of the URL to include a name (as :permalink) rather than the ID number, by defining a to_param function in the model. This works fine when accessing the first model, however when accessing the second, it reverts to using the model's ID in the URL. It is functional, however I would like consistency in the URLs.

My route is set up as follows:

```
resources :coins do
  resources :questions
end
```

As it stands the URL is in the form:

```
coins/:id/questions/:id
```

I would like it to be in the form:

```
coins/:permalink/questions/:id
```

model:

```
class Coin < ApplicationRecord
    validates :link_name, :currency_name, presence: true
    has_many :questions

    def to_param
        "#{permalink}"
    end
end
```

How would I go about redefining the Question routing to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :coins, :param => :permalink do
  resources :questions
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.